# Operand should contain 1 column(s) ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have 3 model Shop Section and Price, Section have shop_id and Price have section_id
How can i show prices in Shop view?
controller/shop_controller.rb

```
...
def show    
    @metod_one = Magazine.find(params[:id])
    @method_two = Section.find(:all, :conditions => ['shop_id = ?', @method_one])
    @method_three = Price.find(:id, :conditions => ['section_id = ?', @method_two])
end
...
```

This method don't work
Mysql::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT * FROM `prices`   WHERE (`prices`.`id` = '--- :id\n' AND (section_id = 5480,5482,5483,5485))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the `in` operator:

```
@method_three = Price.find(:all, :conditions => ['section_id in (?)', @method_two])
```

Comment: tnks, but don't work for me
Couldn't find Price with ID=id AND (section_id in (4341,4342,4343))